# How to solve this dependencies conflict warning using Unity Mediation?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dependencies, mobile-ad-mediation

I'm making a mobile game using Unity for Android. My problem is that I have a dependencies conflict error whenever I'm installing the Unity Mediation package. Here is the error :

```
Some conflicting dependencies were found.
The following dependency versions were modified:
com.unity3d.mediation:mediation-sdk:[1.0,2.0[ --> com.unity3d.mediation:mediation-sdk: 
[1.0,2.0[
com.unity3d.mediation:unityads-adapter:[1.0,2.0[ --> com.unity3d.mediation:unityads- 
adapter:[1.0,2.0[

UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log (string,Google.LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<GradleResolution>b__2                 
(GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<>c__DisplayClass7_1:<GradleResolution>b__9 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext ()
Google.RunOnMainThread/<>c:<ExecuteAll>b__24_0 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run (System.Action,bool)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<GradleResolution>b__8         
(GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog/ProgressReporter:SignalComplete ()
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog/ProgressReporter:CommandLineToolCompletion     
(GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/<>c__DisplayClass4_1:<RunAsync>b__1 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext ()
Google.RunOnMainThread/<>c:<ExecuteAll>b__24_0 ()
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

I have been looking for a solution for many hours. The real problem is that because of this dependencies conflict I can't build my project because the Gradle plugin won't work (the given error being the usage of a deprecated command). Have you got any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Conflicting dependencies is not necessarily an error. Does the resolve say it succeeded or failed? What is the actual error you're getting when building?

Comment: The resolve itself succeeds, and the error that occurs when building involves trying to set the property « gradle.enableR8=false » which doesn’t work for gradle 5+

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the conflicting dependencies. You need to use a custom gradle properties template and remove the offending line from the template file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776130/how-to-fix-gradle-build-failed-on-unity

Comment: That’s what I did but it didn’t work. Unity will just open a text box saying that I can’t manage compile plugins manually. I think the problem might come from the dependencies conflict because the project built correctly until I added the Unity Mediation package.